# Create MySQL View from Lookup Table and Actual Data

Tags: mysql, view

I would like to create a view from a lookup table and actual data.  I have two questions.

1. How would you accomplish this?
2. Should I try to do it this way?

## Senerio

**Table Name: `steps`**

Table structure with values:
There are other columns hence the ( ... )

```
| id | Name     | ... |
| 1  | Step One | ... |
| 2  | Step Two | ... |
```

**Table Name: `steps_completed`**

Table structure with values:

```
| user_id | steps_id |
| 1       | 1        |
| 2       | 1        |
| 2       | 2        |
```

## Results Wanted

View Structure and Values wanted:

```
| user_id | step_one | step_two |
| 1       | 1        | 0        |
| 1       | 1        | 1        |
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a cross tab query. The only way I've seen it done is via a stored procedure like this: [Cross Tab Query](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/creating-crosstabs-in-mysql.html)

Comment: This does look like it would work, but I ended up using PHP to do what I needed.  I could organize it much better making it more maintainable.  Thanks.